# Benders Deceiver Stun ability vs event card that causes unit to move

Tags: summoner-wars

The Benders Deceiver "stun" ability states:

> Common enemy units that begin a turn adjacent to this Deceiver cannot
> move or attack during that turn.

And the Cave Filth Overwork event states:

> Choose a common Unit you control. You may immediately move up to 2
> spaces and attack with that Unit if able.

Which one takes precedence? Can the Overwork event cause a stunned unit to move?